Salesforce How to perform batch processing within an Apex class
I am currently processing an insert in an Apex class and I am getting an error “Too many DML rows: 10001”.
I would like to process more than 10,000 data items, and I would like to do several inserts in a batch process, etc. How can I call the batch from within an Apex class?
Does anyone know how to INSERT or UPDATE more than 10,000 data items?
I tried processing in a schedule batch, but this time we wanted to call the batch within an Apex class, not a schedule batch, so we were not able to do the processing we expected.

You can just call Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch()); in your "regular" apex code and it'll be enqueued for execution (async, in the background), typically couple seconds after "this" transaction finishes.
What is your data source? If it can be queried (add a new line item to thousands of Opportunities) - great, a typical batch would do the job.
If it's something else (you have an in-memory list of > 10K records to insert or something you're parsing out of a CSV) - you can still batch process them but the class will have to look bit different. Read up about "Iterable", this alternative form of what the start() method should return: public (Database.QueryLocator | Iterable<sObject>) start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {}
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/137451/799 is a fairly simple example (it doesn't actually implement iterable, it's simpler than the official docs and if you have just a plain List<MyObject__c> it could work very well)
You'd still be constrained by heap size (memory) when passing your "more than 10K" from the "normal" Apex to the batch. Batches have 12 MB limit, yes - but synchronous apex has just 6.
